# Can I use Google CardDAV sync on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, data-synchronization, contacts, carddav

Is it possible for me to use Google's excellent CardDAV contact sync service on my OS X (10.8) computer?

It works very well on iOS, but the same settings do not work on a computer.

Comment: On Snow Leopard, I had to use iSync to sync Google contacts with the Address Book. You might want to try that, too.

Comment: @str iSync was removed with Mountain Lion :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I use it on Mountain Lion.

Details here:http://tech.kateva.org/2013/02/google-contact-sync-on-mountain-lion.html.

It's not clear to me how Contacts.app is merging Google/iCloud duplicates that arise if you use iCloud, or handling editing of those duplicates. There's no support for Google Group/Tag relationships or Mac Group/Tag relationships.

Nobody has gotten it working on Snow Leopard, though if you want to try that (do publish) Hsiaoi's technique is a good start (http://www.hsiaoi.com/blog/?p=512). I suspect SSL is a problem.

I believe it also works on Lion but I've not tested.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like CardDAV sync feature is only avaliable from iOS devices. I did however find an [article](http://512pixels.net/2012/12/contacts-google-carddav/) showing how you can do so on your mac, it could be worth a try.

> After opening Contacts, go to the app’s preferences pane. Navigate to
>   the “Accounts” section:
>   http://ismh.s3.amazonaws.com/2012-12-16-google-contacts-1.png
>   Hit the plus sign to add an account. Here are the required settings:
>   Account type: CardDAV:
>   Username: Your Gmail Account
>   Your password
>   Server address: google.com
>
> Hit the “Create” button:
>   http://ismh.s3.amazonaws.com/2012-12-16-google-contacts-2.png
>   Contacts.app will then ask if you want use these credentials for other
>   types of information. Select what you wish and press the “Create”
>   button again.
>
> Once the account is listed in Contact.app’s preferences, go to the
>   “General” section and set your Google account to be the default
>   account:
>   http://ismh.s3.amazonaws.com/2012-12-16-google-contacts-3.png
>
> By default, the application defaults to saving vCards locally on the
>   Mac, which means information added from other programs won’t end up in
>   the Google cloud.

Comment: That last tip about setting it as the default was what I needed, as recently CardDAV started working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *Accounts* tab of the *Contacts* preferences give you an option to add a CardDAV acount:

[image]

Simply use that. If that doesn't work for you, please post a more specific problem description.

Comment: This option doesn't work, unfortunately. I had tried this option, and also mentioned it in my question.

Comment: You weren't very specific about that. How exactly "doesn't it work"?

Comment: I receive this error message when trying to set it up: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/99068c76-b570-4798-a452-ecbe90c3d0a7/2599ab03251d41005de5c2362bec9bf1

Comment: I've just done it, and its working in OSX 10.8.2, But I configured it in System Preferences -> Mail contacts & Calendars -> add other accont -> CardDAV.